# running inference on coral edgetpu generates IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-lite, google-coral, edge-tpu

I was trying to run post training int8 quantized detection model (generated through tflite and coral edgetpu compiler)using 'detect_image.py' example provided on their official website.

```
python3 examples/detect_image.py   --model test_data/int8_model_edgetpu.tflite   --labels test_data/tflite_label_map.txt   --input test_data/parrot.jpg   --output ${HOME}/parrot.jpg
```

but it's resulting into following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/detect_image.py", line 109, in <module>
    main()
  File "examples/detect_image.py", line 88, in main
    objs = detect.get_objects(interpreter, args.threshold, scale)
  File "/home/mha/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycoral/adapters/detect.py", line 237, in get_objects
    return [make(i) for i in range(count) if scores[i] >= score_threshold]
  File "/home/mha/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycoral/adapters/detect.py", line 237, in <listcomp>
    return [make(i) for i in range(count) if scores[i] >= score_threshold]
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce this?

Comment: converting tf saved_model into tflite supported saved_model file, then converted that file into .tflite model format(int quantized using representative data), and then compiled it using coral edgetpu_compiler.